# How to filter by price ranges in PHP / MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a function that will filter out products based on price ranges.

A user can select more price ranges at once (via checkboxes). The checkboxes looks like this:

```
    <label>0-500 <input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="1"/></label>
    <label>500-1000 <input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="2"/></label>
    <label>1000-2000 <input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="3"/></label>
```

When the user submits the filter form with 2 checkboxes checked, it sends me an array which looks like this `[0 => "2", 1 => "3"]`.

Then I'd filter the products via SQL query (`SELECT * FROM ... WHERE price > 500 AND price < 2000` // very simplified).

The thing is I don't know **how to properly get those price ranges from the array**, which doesnt include it specifically.

I would highly appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe it's really a problem of poor user interface design. Perhaps it would be better if the user could just select a max and a min?

Comment: I thought about that. But I have seen few website using this kind of filtering and prefer this way.

Comment: OK. How do those sites do it? I have to say though, as a user, it seems really weird to me that I might select 0-9 and 20-29, but not 10-19 !?!?!?

Comment: I haven't described it very well. Take a look [here](http://mobilni-telefony.heureka.cz) (the left sidebar with checkboxes) to see what I mean

Comment: Well, I think that site works by using a bit of javascript to 'post' an array (p[]) every time a checkbox is ticked or unticked. The backend database has already divided the products up according to price bracket. So it effectively resends a query like `SELECT * FROM products WHERE price_bracket IN(498,499,500)`. I think this is an odd way to filter on price!

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea about that. I might change it to the min - max feature.

Comment: I prefer something like what happens on Kiva - which updates both the left column and right column simultaneously, but that might be a bit too complicated to implement. So here's another example that I really love... http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/GFbAs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
//parameter like [0 => "2", 1 => "3"]
function getQuery($form){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE false";
    if (in_array("1", $form)){
        $query .= " OR price >= 0 AND price <= 500";
    }
    if (in_array("2", $form)){
        $query .= " OR price >= 500 AND price <= 1000";
    }
    if (in_array("3", $form)){
        $query .= " OR price => 1000 AND price <= 2000";
    }
    return $query;
}
```

the function will return the query based on your checkboxes array

## Edit

(with Aris idea)

```
//parameter like [0 => "500-1000", 1 => "1000-2000"]

function getQuery($form){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE false";
    foreach ($form as $range){
        $ranges = explode("-", $range);
        $from = ranges[0];
        $to = ranges[1];
        $query .= " OR BETWEEN $from AND $to";
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to map it somehow. For example value="1" means "0-500".

Another solution is to set the value to the actual range, then parse it and get the minimum and maximum prices:

```
    <label>0-500 <input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="0-500"/></label>
    <label>500-1000 <input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="500-1000"/></label>
    <label>1000-2000 <input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="1000-2000"/></label>
```

In this case your array will look like below:

```
[0 => "500-1000", 1 => "1000-2000"]
```

Parse the strings and insert in the sql query

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried to do make it this way but it wasn't working as supposed. I will rather use the min - max input.

Comment: you need to read the value, parse in 2 pieces and make sure you have 2 numbers. number formatting between PHP and mysql can be tricky sometimes. maybe that is why it was not working.